# java.sql.ResultSet returns trimmed string after increasing column length

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, resultset

I have an `alpha` table on a Oracle 11g DB with `id INTEGER`, `data VARCHAR2(5)`, and `last_update TIMESTAMP` columns in it.

I query the table using its primary key column (`id` column) from a Java 8 application hosted on WebLogic 12 server. The query is implemented in Spring Framework 4.2's `NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport` class and I fetch the results by iterating the returned `java.sql.ResultSet` object.

So far so good. I get either 0 or 1 record based on the absence or presence of the `id` value supplied in the query. And `data` and `last_update` columns are retrieved as is from the database table.

I had to increase the size of `data` column to 6 bytes for a new requirement using `ALTER TABLE alpha MODIFY data VARCHAR2(6);` statement. And I updated all the rows with 6 character values for `data` column and the current time for `last_update` column. When I query the table from any SQL client, I see the 6 character values for `data` column and the correct `last_update` value that I updated.

But the Java 8 application still retrieves the 5 character value for `data` column. The `last_update` values retrieved are the correct values that I updated. There are no length trimming codes in the application and the getters and setters are in a plain POJO.

I could see a similar issue in [Coderanch](https://coderanch.com/t/644163), but even there I don't see the cause being listed, and a proper fix. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after restarting the WebLogic instances.

Looks like the `PreparedStatement` used by the query cached column length and was relying on that value to retrieve `data` value.